# django ORM aggregate for count

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orm, aggregate, django-orm

I want to get count of scheduled test ride and completed test ride of user

```py
obj= TestRide.objects.filter(feature=feature_obj).aggregate(
    scheduled_count=(
        Count('status', filter=Q(status='Scheduled'))
    ),
    completed_count=(
        Count('status', filter=Q(status='Completed'))
    ),
)
```

I'm getting the same count value in scheduled_count and completed_count I think my filter is not working can anyone help me out
thanks

Answer (score 0):

**can you try this:**

```
test = TestRide.objects
test_scheduled_count = test.filter(feature=feature_obj,status='Scheduled').aggregate(
    scheduled_count=Count('status')).get('scheduled_count')

test_completed_count = test.filter(feature=feature_obj,status='Completed').aggregate(
    completed_count=Count('status')).get('completed_count')
```